# Spring - Get request header without using @RequestHeader annotation

Tags: spring, kotlin

My code is currently implemented like so:

```
fun test(@RequestHeader key: String) { ... }
```

But I wan't to remove the parameter, so it's something like this:

```
fun test() { request.headers("key") ... }
```

Is this possible with Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autowire **HttpServletRequest** in your class and use it within the functions defined in the class for example:

```
class MyClass {
   @Autowired
   lateinit var request: HttpServletRequest

   fun test() { request.getHeader("key") ... }
}
```